# Simultaneity problem with train and platform observer

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, coordinate-systems, inertial-frames, observers

The problem is quite simple but there might be something I'm not getting right or I must have missed some concept. Suppose we have a train moving in $y (ĵ)$ with $ v = v(-ĵ)$. The reference event is when João and Maria see each other $t = 0$ in Maria reference frame. When they do so, Maria presses the button which activates the flashes in (1) and (2). Lets suppose that the flashes are so close from Zé and Ana that they are illuminated at the same time the flash is activated. Zé and João are far apart by L, so is Ana and João (in Maria reference frame) (considering $v = 0.8\cdot c$ and L = $7.2\cdot10^9$)

[image: Train and Plataform]

I've done the following. Reference event, Maria sees João. Where $S^{R}_{M}$ means Maria reference frame and $S^{R}_{J}$ means João reference frame, Reference event.
$S^{R}_{M} : (x^{R}_{M},y^{R}_{M},z^{R}_{M},t^{R}_{M}) = (0,0,0,0)$ 
$S^{R}_{J} : (x^{R}_{J},y^{R}_{J},z^{R}_{J},t^{R}_{J}) = (0,0,0,0)$

Event A : flash one illuminates Zé: 
$S^{A}_{M} : (x^{A}_{M},y^{A}_{M},z^{A}_{M},t^{A}_{M}) = (0,-7.2\cdot10^9,0,0)$

doing the Lorentz Transformation we have: 
$S^{A}_{J} : (x^{A}_{J},y^{A}_{J},z^{A}_{J},t^{A}_{J}) = (0, -1.2\cdot10^{10},0, -32)$

Event B : flash one illuminates Ana: 
$S^{B}_{M} : (x^{B}_{M},y^{B}_{M},z^{B}_{M},t^{B}_{M}) = (0,7.2\cdot10^9,0,0)$

once again, doing the LT we have: 
$S^{B}_{J} : (x^{B}_{J},y^{B}_{J},z^{B}_{J},t^{B}_{J}) = (0, 1.2\cdot10^{10},0, 32)$

Event C : João sees Zé in João reference frame: 
João only sees Zé when the flash is activated and, in João reference frame, light runs through $\lambda$ which is $L$ space contracted. Given by: 
$\lambda = \gamma\cdot L$ 
where $\gamma$ is the Lorentz factor.
So then we have:
$t^{C}_{J}  + t^{B}_{J} = \lambda/c + t^{B}_{J} =  40 + 32 = 72 \:s$

Event D : João sees Ana in João reference frame: 
The same from event C but now we shall use $t^{A}_{J} $ 
So then we have:
$t^{C}_{J}  + t^{A}_{J} = \lambda/c + t^{A}_{J} =  40 - 32 = 8 \:s$

My struggle is the order of events in this problem, the way I've done it is:

Flash 1 illuminates Zé, João sees Maria, João sees Zé, Flash 2 illuminates Ana and João sees Ana.

Which means that Flash one is activated BEFORE João sees Maria, but Maria only activates the flashes when she sees João. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: What do you mean by "sees"?   Do you mean that literally, as in light reflected from Maria enters Joas' eyes?

Comment: @garyp I mean, Maria will only press the button when she passes through João.